# How are answers ranked?

Tags: support, answers, user-interface

For the large amount of questions that contain more than one answer, how does the Ask Ubuntu system decide which answers appear on top of others?

Comment: Depends on the sorting you choose, Votes, oldest or active. Look top right above the answers.

Comment: Wow, I didn't notice that. I'll mark this as solved if you put that in an answer.

Comment: Done............ IDK why but a lot of people don't seem to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the sorting you choose,

Votes, oldest or active.

Look top right above the answers

> [image]